# Access-Allow-Control-Origin não restringe acesso de outros domínios

Tags: node.js, http, cors

Estou criando uma Api com `Nodejs`, onde configuro o cabeçalho da aplicação para que funcione corretamente o **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing**.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

Onde no código eu restrinjo o acesso apenas para localhost:3000 poder acessar os recursos. `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");`

Só que mesmo deixando o acesso restrito para apenas uma aplicação, **consigo acessar os recursos dessa Api de qualquer Domínio.** 
Qual o problema no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` que não funciona?

Comment: Então como é a url que você usa para acessar api de outro dominio?

Comment: eu acesso essa Api do navegador do meu celular, que é outro ip totalmente diferente, e mesmo assim ele me retorna os recusos da Api @AndersonMendes

Comment: Entendi, eu uso o modulo [Cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) para controlar o acesso, tem o mesmo principio, mas com mais funcionalidades da uma olhada qualquer me chama que ajudo a configurar.